# mysql : How save/log sql on update on certain table?

Tags: mysql

I would like to save sql logs (can be on text or into a mysql table) only on updates ob table "members".

Any idea ? Maybe triggers ?

Comment: Check general query log: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html

Comment: use trigger to store the altered data before and after, also you can save the all logs in mysql log.